# How do you find duplicate methods?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

Without examining each method, how can I find duplicate methods in a class? Duplicate methods are defined as the same code within the method body and, likely but not guaranteed, the same method signature.

I'm cleaning up, re-designing, and refactoring some projects. One thought I have is to copy all the utility methods into one class, find the duplicates, delete them, and move on to the next task. I'd rather not look at each method individually to find duplicates.

Edit 1: Just to be clear, the duplicate methods are identical code. The result of copying & pasting. This is not about finding duplicated functionality, i.e., a method with a different name and different method structure varibale names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are tools that try to automatically find duplicated code (within the same class, or across an entire project), while allowing for minor edits (e.g., variable renames, changing constants, etc.) that don't affect the overall behaviour of the method.

A short list can be found at [Duplicate code (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_code#Tools).

Comment: will these tool understands complex logic written in two ways?

Comment: @Saurabh, I doubt that.. you're talking about automatic formal proofs of equivalence. I think what's being referred to here is detecting syntactic variats.

Comment: No, they generally operate by looking for textual similarity and don't consider semantic equivalence (e.g., multiplying by two is generally the same as shifting left by one bit, but that's very unlikely to be detected as duplicate code by a tool).

Answer (score 1):

I would use a similarity analyzer such as Simian (http://www.redhillconsulting.com.au/products/simian/). Yes, it's a commercial product, but inexpensive compared to the cost of developing something yourself. It will find copy/pasted code and not necessarily along method boundaries. If someone copies/pastes the same foreach loop a dozen times, it will find that too.

N.B. I am not in any way employed or related to RedHill Consulting, the makers of Simian. I've just used their product in the past and hence it jumped to mind.

Comment: will these tool understands complex logic written in two ways?

Comment: No, the purpose is looking for copy/pasted code. Generally they don't even do syntactic analysis on the code, but are just raw dup finders. Many will identify similar runs of code with minor modifications. (e.g. Renames of variables.)

Answer (score 0):

> **Duplicate methods are defined as the same code within the method body**

i don't thinkk , there is some intelligent tool which can do this job, you either need to do manually or write a program which can identify the same logic written in different methods

> **likely but not guaranteed, the same method signature**

same method signature with different method name is possible but same method name with same signature is not allowded by the C# compiler

**Best way is to established code guidelines and code reviews.**